# Custom View ui elements display

Tags: ios, swift

I have two custom views(say View A and View B) sub class of UIView. Each of them loads on UIViewController on different button tap.The View B sits on the top of View A.
So the View B covers the UI elements of View A.
Now I want only one textfield  of View A should be showing over View B.
Can anybody help me please ?

Comment: Is there any way to do it ?

Comment: Use bringSubviewToFront

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add View B as subview of View A and then call bringSubview(toFront:) for textField.

```
let viewA = ...
let viewB = ...
viewA.addSubview(viewB)
viewA.bringSubview(toFront: viewA.someTextField)
```